# CSV Upload & Parse it into HTML Table using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I'm developing a web application.My App is using Javascript, PHP, HTML. I already done apply code to upload xlsx , attach it on screen .

Here's my Code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="simple-excel.js"></script>
<table width=50% align="left" border=0 STYLE="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:9.2%"><b>Load CSV file</b></td>
            <td style="width:1%"><b>:</b></td> 
            <td style="width:15%"><input type="file" id="fileInputCSV" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 <table id="result"></table>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            // check browser support
            // console.log(SimpleExcel.isSupportedBrowser);

            var fileInputCSV = document.getElementById('fileInputCSV'); 


            // when local file loaded
            fileInputCSV.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

                // parse as CSV
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                var csvParser = new SimpleExcel.Parser.CSV();
                csvParser.setDelimiter(',');
                csvParser.loadFile(file, function () {

                    // draw HTML table based on sheet data
                    var sheet = csvParser.getSheet();
                    var table = document.getElementById('result');
                    table.innerHTML = "";
                    sheet.forEach(function (el, i) {                    
                        var row = document.createElement('tr');
                        el.forEach(function (el, i) {
                            var cell = document.createElement('td');
                            cell.innerHTML = el.value;
                            row.appendChild(cell);
                        });
                        table.appendChild(row);
                    });                    

                });
            });



        </script>
```

Here's my UI

[image]

How do i supposed to do for hide/erase the null cell(Red Mark)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put some condition inside el.forEach

Like this

```
 el.forEach(function (el, i) {
                          if(el.value!="")
                          {
                              var cell = document.createElement('td');
                              cell.innerHTML = el.value;
                              row.appendChild(cell);
                          }
                         });
```

Comment: Really?  Gosh, how did you come up with that?

Comment: @slambeth Yeah. I just tried it all the time :D anyway thankyou :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems your CSV has an empty line at the bottom. Even if it is empty, as far as "sheet" is concerned, it will have one field as long as a carriage return is there.

I'd check to see if the content of the "el" contains anything before executing your el.forEach()

Comment: I already delete the last row in my csv file. it's always shown like that. so, do u have other solutions? thanks

Comment: One way or another, you are appending both a tr, and a td when you don't need to.  I'll rest on my suggestion that you should check the content of el, and perhaps verify that el has more than one column/element in it before you enter the forEach